# How to access properties via reflection?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have some Devexpress controls.

I'm trying to set some properties using reflection.

Let's say TextEdit.

Normally, to set the border color of the text box, I would do :

```
TextEdit1.Properties.Appearance.BorderColor = whatever...
```

Using reflection I'm trying :

```
SetProperty(TextEdit1, "Properties.Appearance.BorderColor", RGB(200, 200, 200))

'Where SetProperty sub is
Private Sub SetProperty(ByVal Control As Object, ByVal PropertyName As String, ByVal Args As Object)
    If Not IsNothing(Control.GetType.GetProperty(PropertyName)) Then
        CallByName(Control, PropertyName, CallType.Set, Args)
    End If
End Sub
```

This code doesn't work because the result of **Control.GetType.GetProperty(PropertyName)** is always null.

Does anyone know how to access this "compound" type of properties ?

Thanks

Comment: It is, *cough*, a bit more complicated than that.  You first have to do a Get for the Properties property, then a Get for the Appearance property, then a Set for the BorderColor property.  All hail the compiler just doing this for you.

Comment: What does your cough means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
Dim prop = TextEdit1.GetType.GetProperty("Properties").GetValue(TextEdit1)
Dim appe = prop.GetType.GetProperty("Appearance").GetValue(prop)
appe.GetType.GetProperty("BorderColor").SetValue(appe, Color.Red)
```